# How to select rows in a given range?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file with 2 columns:

```
head positions_vcf
4 68264840
4 52784678
4 52788987
4 52795404
4 52800097
4 52801203
4 52804052
4 52804766
4 52804941
4 52805425
4 52807245
4 52809203
4 52809705
4 52810211
4 52810307
4 52811970
4 52812994
4 52814042
4 52814185
4 52815272
```

I need to select only rows in which the second column is within the range of "52804760-52809700".
my desired out_put

```
desired_output
4 52804766
4 52804941
4 52805425
4 52807245
4 52809203
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$2 >= 52804760 && $2 <= 52809700' positions_vcf
```

Comment: or more awk-ishly: `awk '$2 >= 52804760 && $2 <= 52809700'`

Comment: For readability, I like to use this style: `52804760 <= $2 && $2 <= 52809700`